# Convert cell array with sub cells into numeric array

Tags: matlab, cell

Assume I have `A` that is a 64x1 cell array.

Each of the 64 cells contains another cell with a string (which is a number, i.e. `11`)

```
A{1, 1}{1, 1} = ’11’ (char)
A{2, 1}{1, 1} = ’13’ (char)
```

How can I create a numeric array such as

```
A = [11,13,…]
```

The `cell2mat` function seems to work only on “first level” cell array:
`cell2mat` does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to convert the contents of each individual cell in `A` to doubles.

```
A{1, 1}{1, 1} = '11';
A{2, 1}{1, 1} = '13';

A_array = cellfun(@(a) str2double(a), A)
```

Breakdown of the function: `@(a)` passes the contents of each cell of `A` to the variable `a`, which can be converted to doubles using `str2double(a)`.

Comment: Hi rinkert, thanks a lot for your response. Works perfectly! It's very helpful. I finally understand how to use the cellfun function. Very handy. All the best, C

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, however you need split it to two steps. Let's assume we have simple 1x4 string array:

```
A= {'11','13','15','17'};
```

To convert it you need store the content in temporary variable `S`, then use `sscanf` to generate final result:

```
S = sprintf('%s ', A{:});
Result = sscanf(S, '%f')
```

The only problem is that it will be column vector. If you need it in a row, you can just `transpose(Results)`.

Comment: This does not work since each cell in `A` contains a cell, and not a character array as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. If I've got it right, you're talking about a cell array like `asd` below

```
asd=cell(61,1);
for ii=1:64
   asd{ii}={['test',num2str(ii)]}
end
```

If I understand your goal correctly, I think the following does it somewhat neatly

```
A=char([asd{:}])
```

Then if you want to convert the strings to numbers (which wouldn't work for my test, but might for your strings), just use `str2num` on this new vector

Answer (score 0):

Transform `A` into a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of cells, then [horizontally concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) these cells and finally apply [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html);

```
A = str2double([A{:}]);
```

Comment: Dear Sardar, the str2double function also works very well. Thanks for your help!